# Save Data from form on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webforms

How to save data from the form by clicking on the button?
I do not understand where the error is. 
As planned, when you click on the data from the field stored in the variable "master"

For example I use this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_forms.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form novalidate>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    <button ng-click="copyData()">Click Me!</button>
  </form>
  <p>form = {{user}}</p>
  <p>master = {{master}}</p>
</div>
  <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {uder.firstName};
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };
    $scope.reset();
    $scope.copyData=function(){
        $scope.master1=angular.copy($scope.mas);
       $scope.copyData();
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly you wanted to do here?

Comment: Save data from form by click "Click me!"

Comment: which data you want to save and where?

Comment: City name. String data.

Comment: please go through the documentation given in the w3schools link. you have taken first name as the input, and you need city?

Comment: We believe, that I should keep the type of string. Then I'll post it as part of the request on openveatnermap,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all!
A working version:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.username = 'World';

    $scope.sayHello = function() {
      $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
    };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
-<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="weather 2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="scopeExample">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
    Your name:
      <input type="text" ng-model="username">
      <button ng-click='sayHello()'>greet</button>
    <hr>
    {{greeting}}
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a typo error. Replace *{uder.firstname}* with *{user.firstname}*.

You should put some effort on understanding scopes and how you can use variables, that you declare on scopes.

You declare an input with *ng-model="firstname"*, but on the controller you have a user object with the attribute *firstname*. You should change your form to:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
<button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
<button ng-click="copyData()">Click Me!</button>
```

and in your controller

```
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.user = { firstname:"", lastname:"" }; //init your user
      $scope.master = user.firstname; //or user object itself, dont understand what exactly you would like to achieve
      $scope.reset = function() {
           $scope.user = $scope.master; 
};

$scope.copyData=function(){ }//call your onclick event
     //set the data, that you want directly here. Recursion will not work.
```

More information about [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) and [forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) can definitely help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,There are some typos like `$scope.mas` and  `{uder.firstname}`.

Inspite of that you are assigning a property to the $scope object using ng-model directive but in the controller you are trying to access it using an object called user which would be undefined at this point.Here is the change in your code

```
 First Name:<br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
            <button ng-click="reset()">
                RESET</button>
            <button ng-click="copyData()">
                Click Me!</button>
            </form>
            <p>
                form = {{user}}</p>
            <p>
                master = {{master}}</p>
```

The controller would be like

```
 $scope.reset = function() {
                    $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
                };
                 $scope.reset();
                $scope.copyData = function () {
                 $scope.master = user.firstName;
                $scope.master1=angular.copy($scope.master);
                $scope.copyData();
               };
```